# Custom Notification Layout Issue Android Version 12

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, layout, push-notification, android-notifications

I have created custom notification but app name and small notification icon is also coming in it how to remove this issue android version 12. while android version 11 coming on right.

Comment: Could you please provide screenshoot please about expected result and actual reault?

Answer (score 1):

According to ask description Android have changed custom notification behaviour starting from Android 12. Check here is [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#custom-notifications)